# Watching user activities in iphone SDK outside sandbox?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, sandbox

1)   Is it possible to watch user's all activities of iPhone through iPhone SDK Programming As Symantec has developed  norton online family inwhich user's iphone safari activities are savedin hidden way?

2)   Is it possible to handle outside of sandbox environment which has been created using the application we install?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if it is possible to actively monitor what websites a user is visiting using the safari browser and have that information to use in you're own app, it's not.

You can't access the data of another application.

Comment: did you install Symantec's  norton online family  in your mobile,it gets safari's history in hidden way.How is it possible?

Comment: @mirdad it is quite possible that Symantec has received a special permit from Apple to use a private API. Quite bad, if you ask me. It is no app's business what sites I visit or what messages I type, etc. The sandbox is there for a reason.

Everything is of course available when targeting a jailbroken iOS devices.